# Some questions about uniform continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I got the following questions:

Let $f$ be a real valued function of a real variable:

(1) If $f$ is continuous and bounded on the interval (a,b) (meaning there exist $M,L\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in (a,b), M \leq f(x) \leq L$), then $f$ is uniformly continuous on (a,b)?
(2) If $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and uniformly continuous on every **finite** interval (meaning that the interval is of the form $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ or $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$), then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb{R}$?
(3) If $f$ is uniformly continuous on (0,1), then $f$ is bounded on (0,1)?
(4) If $f$ is bounded, continuous and monotonic on (0,1), then $f$ is uniformly continuous on (0,1)?

If the statement is true prove it and if not give a counter example:

I tried to prove and to find a counter example without so much success. Thanks.

Comment: Have you really done nothing that you can show us?

Comment: There's a typo in (2) - I suspect you mean " and **uniformly continuous** on every finite interval"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**: Consider $f(x) = \sin\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$.

**2**: Consider $f(x) = \sin (x^2)$.

**3**: Uniform continuity means that you can pick an $\delta$ and always find a $\epsilon$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \delta$ if $|x -y| < \epsilon$. Now pick any $\delta$, and find the corresponding $\epsilon$. Then you can cover $(0,1)$ with finitely many intervals of length $\epsilon$. Use that to put a global bound on $|f(x) - f(y)|$ for $x,y \in (0,1)$, using the *local* bound that uniform continuity gives you

**4**: Extend $f$ to $[0,1]$ by using the boundedness and monotonicity. Then use that $[0,1]$ is compact, in particular that every covering with open intervals contains a finite subcover. This allows you to convert the local bound on $|f(x)-f(y)|$ that you get from $f$'s continutity to a global bound that shows it's uniform continuity.

Comment: Question (2): But it is required that $f$ will be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x^2$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ (since $f$ is not bounded above on $\mathbb{R}$), then  $f(x) = x^2$ is not a good counter example (if (2) false).

Comment: @JohnSaita Yeah, I missed that requirement. So use $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ instead...

Comment: Thanks for (2). Now I don't fully understand how in (3) can I put a bound on $|f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$, I do understand that we can cover $(0,1)$ with finitely many intervals of length $\epsilon$ and that for all $x,y$ in such an interval we get that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, but how can I put a bound on $|f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$ using this fact. Do I need to to take the maximum all the supremums and the minimum of all the infimums of each interval?

Comment: @JohnSaita You have that $f$ changes by at most $\delta$ between $a$ and $b$, and *also* changed by at most $\delta$ between $c < b$ and d$ (i.e., your intervals overlap, i.e. look like this `{..(..}..)`). How much can $f$ then in the worst-case change between $a$ and $d$?

Comment: @JohnSaita Write that change as $|f(d) - f(a)| = |(f(d) - f(x)) + (f(x) - f(a))|$ where $x \in (c,b)$ (i.e. in the overlapping region$. Now use the triangle inequality.

Comment: You mean the change is at most $2 \delta$ and therefore we can conclude that $|f(x)-f(y)|<$the number of $\epsilon$s $+1$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @JohnSaita Yes, mostly. But the global bound is not $\epsilon n$ but $\delta n$ of course! To turn this into a formal proof, you first pick a $\delta$, then find $\epsilon$ (uniform continuity).  For $x < y$ you can then say $D(x,y) = |f(y) - f(x)| = |(f(y) - f(y - \epsilon/2)) + (f(y - \epsilon/2) - f(y - \epsilon)) + \ldots + (f(y - n\epsilon/2) - f(x))|$ where $n$ is such that $0 \leq y - n\epsilon/2 - x < \epsilon$. Finally use the triangle inequality on $D(x,y)$ show that it's bounded by $n\delta$ (or maybe $(n+1)\delta$, I didn't check).

Comment: Thanks. The exact proof is too technical.

Comment: @JohnSaita ??? You can write that whole thing down in about three or four lines, that's about as concise as it gets. If you're interested in handwaving arguments, not proofs, then say so in your question, and I won't bother next time...

Comment: I meant too technical just as fact about the proof, I didn't expected the proof to be that technical, but not that I won't prove it myself again, and thanks for your help, sorry if what I said has not been understood properly.